# Displaying RGB raster on QGIS with no enhancement with Python Console?

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis

I'm working with a RGB raster on QGIS 2.6.1, on a Windows 7 machine.

I need to set the Contrast Enhancement option to No Enhancement with the Python Console (not through the Layer Properties window).
I have developed a simple script, inspired by this discussion: [QGIS Scripting problem updating contrast enhancements for raster layers using bandStatistics](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102094/qgis-scripting-problem-updating-contrast-enhancements-for-raster-layers-using-ba)

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
renderer = layer.renderer()
ContrastEnhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement.NoEnhancement

for Band in range(3):
    if Band == 0:
        myBand = layer.renderer().redBand()
    elif Band == 1:
        myBand = layer.renderer().greenBand()
    elif Band == 2:
        myBand = layer.renderer().blueBand()
    myType = layer.renderer().dataType(myBand)
    myEnhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement(myType)
    myEnhancement.setContrastEnhancementAlgorithm(ContrastEnhancement,True)
    if Band == 0:
        layer.renderer().setRedContrastEnhancement(myEnhancement)
    elif Band == 1:
        layer.renderer().setGreenContrastEnhancement(myEnhancement)
    elif Band == 2:
        layer.renderer().setBlueContrastEnhancement(myEnhancement)

layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Unfortunately, it does not work and the layer becomes not visible.
It seems that it is not handling correctly the min/max values of the bands. Any suggestion?

Comment: You need a 'ContrastEnhancement' for each band to 'StretchToMinimumMaximum' instead of 'NoEnhancement'.

Answer (score 2):

Your script works as it is expected because you need a 'ContrastEnhancement' for each band to 'StretchToMinimumMaximum' instead of 'NoEnhancement'. I modified your script to calculate minimum and maximun values for each band by using 'bandStatistics' method from **QgsDataProvider** class. These values were set manually at the code and the rgb image 'natural_earth' was used to test it.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
renderer = layer.renderer()
provider = layer.dataProvider()

bands = renderer.usesBands()

min = [provider.bandStatistics(band, QgsRasterBandStats.All).minimumValue 
            for band in bands]

max = [provider.bandStatistics(band, QgsRasterBandStats.All).maximumValue 
            for band in bands]

print min
print max

ContrastEnhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement.StretchToMinimumMaximum

myRedBand = layer.renderer().redBand()
myRedType = layer.renderer().dataType(myRedBand)
myRedEnhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement(myRedType)
myRedEnhancement.setContrastEnhancementAlgorithm(ContrastEnhancement,True)
myRedEnhancement.setMinimumValue(62)
myRedEnhancement.setMaximumValue(255)
layer.renderer().setRedContrastEnhancement(myRedEnhancement)

myGreenBand = layer.renderer().greenBand()
myGreenType = layer.renderer().dataType(myGreenBand)
myGreenEnhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement(myGreenType)
myGreenEnhancement.setContrastEnhancementAlgorithm(ContrastEnhancement,True)
myGreenEnhancement.setMinimumValue(89)
myGreenEnhancement.setMaximumValue(255)
layer.renderer().setGreenContrastEnhancement(myGreenEnhancement)

myBlueBand = layer.renderer().blueBand()
myBlueType = layer.renderer().dataType(myBlueBand)
myBlueEnhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement(myBlueType)
myBlueEnhancement.setContrastEnhancementAlgorithm(ContrastEnhancement,True)
myBlueEnhancement.setMinimumValue(90)
myBlueEnhancement.setMaximumValue(255)
layer.renderer().setBlueContrastEnhancement(myBlueEnhancement)

layer.triggerRepaint()
```

After running the code at the Python Console of QGIS not changes were observed at the raster (see next image); as it expected.

[image]

However, if it is modified, for example, the maximum value for the red enhancement to 100:

```
myRedEnhancement.setMaximumValue(100)
```

the result changes drastically; as it can be observed at the next image:

[image]