# bandStatistics becoming slow when specifying extent?

Tags: raster, pyqgis

I'm referring to [QGIS Scripting problem updating contrast enhancements for raster layers using bandStatistics](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102094/qgis-scripting-problem-updating-contrast-enhancements-for-raster-layers-using-ba/102173#102173)

The proposed scripts works fine; however I want to determine the statistics only on that part of the raster that is visible in the canvas. I therefore specified the extent in the bandStatistics command:

```
curExtent = iface.mapCanvas().extent()
myRasterBandStats = layer.dataProvider().bandStatistics(myBand, QgsRasterBandStats.Mean | QgsRasterBandStats.StdDev, curExtent)
```

Unfortunately this significantly slows down the bandStatistics command, which becomes much slower than when loading the min/max in the QGIS interface (properties of the layer => style)